# @Html.ValidationMessageFor is not displaying the error message

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I have the following appsettings values below for my application . For some reason **@Html.ValidationMessageFor** does not display the error message on server side. When i change the key **ClientValidationEnabled** value to **false** , it is working fine. I am using custom validation using Fluent for the model property below

```
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> 
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountSetupView.SecurityAnswer, new { @class = "customText mandatory", @title = @Html.Translate("Answer", ResourceAreas.Onboarding.AccountSetupSecurityAnswerLabel), placeholder = @Html.Translate("Answer", ResourceAreas.Onboarding.AccountSetupTextBoxSecurityAnswerPlaceholderValue), maxlength = "40" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountSetupView.SecurityAnswer)
```

**Fluent Rule**

```
 RuleFor(x => x.SecurityAnswer).ValidEmail().
 WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100007_numbersonly);
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Hi Any idea on this?